# Вставить все значения $_POST в базу данных

Tags: php, mysql

Сейчас в БД происходит запись так:

```
$add = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `products` (`title`, `descr`, `price`, `imgs`, `date`, `cat`, `type`) VALUES ('{$add["title"]}', '{$descr}', '{$price}', '{$imgs}', '{$date}', '{$cat}', '{$type}');");
```

Где каждая переменная - это **$_POST['title']** и т.д.

Как сделать, чтобы автоматически все значения **$_POST** добавлялись в базу?

И мне нужно, чтобы для каждого значения присутствовала фильтрация, например:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$title = stripslashes($title);
$title = htmlspecialchars($title);
$title = trim($title);
```

Comment: Пройдитесь циклом по массиву POST и соберите строку запроса для вставки. Так же в цикле можно сделать фильтр по всем значениям.

Comment: Вот я и спрашиваю, как это сделать. Логику я понимаю.

Comment: Фильтрация для каждого параметра одинаковая?

Comment: Да, верно, одинаковая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSERT

```
$sqlFields = [];
$sqlValues = [];
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $param = stripslashes($value);
    $param = htmlspecialchars($param);
    $param = trim($param);
    $sqlFields[] = $key;
    $sqlValues[] = $param;
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO `products` (`" . implode('`, `', $sqlFields) . "`) VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $sqlValues) . "');";
```

UPDATE

```
$sqlFields = [];
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $param = stripslashes($value);
    $param = htmlspecialchars($param);
    $param = trim($param);
    $sqlFields[] = $key . "='" . $value . "'";
}
$sql = "UPDATE products SET " . implode(', ', $sqlFields) . ";";
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 0, , 6;, )' at line 1

Comment: Точка с запятой в конце + добавить апострафы для значений

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT INTO `products` (" . implode(', ', $sqlFields) . ") VALUES (" . implode(', ', $sqlValues) . ")");
     echo mysql_error();

Comment: Смотрите последнюю строчку

Comment: А тут как? mysql_query("UPDATE `products` SET `title` = '{$title}', `descr` = '{$descr}', `price` = '{$price}', `imgs` = '{$imgs}', `cat` = '{$cat}', `type` = '{$type}' WHERE `products`.`id` = '{$id}'");

Comment: Поможете, пожалуйста?

Comment: Добавил в ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое!